# Load many files into one array - Python

Tags: python, numpy

So, I have to load many .mat files with some features to plot it.

Each array to be plotted is loaded into a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as io


dict1 = io.loadmat('file1.MAT')
dict2 = io.loadmat('file2.MAT')  # type = dict
dict3 = io.loadmat('file3.MAT')
...
```

so I have to take the dictionarie's element I need, to plot after:

```
array1 = dict1['data']
array2 = dict2['data']
array3 = dict3['data']
...
```

After this, I can plot the data. It works, but looks dumb to me (If I have 100 vectors, it will take some time...).  Is there a better way to make this task?

Comment: Use a loop, maybe?

Comment: Yes, thanks Rad. but how can I store this arrays? Into another array with bigger shape? Just beggining, sorry for noob question. \

Comment: If you need an array of arrays, then yes, Python allows that. Just keep on `append`ing them I think (check the documentation).

Comment: Have you looked at [`dict.update(otherdict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are talking about dealing with many matrices, you should manage them as a collection. First, let's define your set of files. It could be a tuple, or a list:

```
Matrix_files = [ 'fileA.MAT', 'file1.MAT', 'no pattern to these names.MAT' ]
```

If they happen to have a pattern, you might try generating the names:

```
Matrix_files = [ 'file{}.MAT'.format(num) for num in range(1,4) ]
```

If they share a common location, you might consider using one of the various directory scanning approaches (`opendir` or `glob`, to name two).

Once you have a list of filenames, you can read the dictionaries in:

```
def read_matrix(filespec):
    from scipy.io import loadmat
    md = loadmat(filespec)
    # process md
    return md
```

With that, you can either get all the data, or get some of the data:

```
All_data = [read_matrix(f) for f in Matrix_files]

Some_data = [read_matrix(f)['data'] for f in Matrix_files]
```

If you only care about the data, you could skip the function definition:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
Just_data = [loadmat(f)['data'] for f in Matrix_files]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Austin Hastings. It is exactly what I´m looking for. It was very helpful!